# Can I synchronize the conda configuration incl. environments?

Tags: python, synchronization, debian, conda

I'm using Miniconda on a Debian machine to develop in Python (using PyCharm). I would like to have the same installation on another Debian machine and would like to keep the installations synchronized. In particular, when I create, modify, or delete environments, I would like these changes to be automatically transferred to the other machine, using standard synchronization software (e.g. Dropbox, Seafile).

I know I can achieve this manually, e.g. using `conda env export` etc., but I'm looking for an automated solution.

The two machines have the same architecture, same operating system, and the same conda installation.

In case this matters, I have installed conda from the deb package (content-equivalent to Miniconda). This leads to the configuration incl. my environments to be located in `~/.conda`, while the `base` environment (which I never changed) is in `/opt/conda`.

I'm aware that packages from the base environment – if cloned – are hardlinked (instead of copied) into a newly created user environment, but I'm willing to lose this advantage.

**The question is:** Can I expect such a synchronization of environments to work? Is there something in the environment structure or contents that is machine-specific and would break if transferred somewhere else?

Comment: Why not just use the regular installer to install into `~/Dropbox` or some other synced folder? Be aware that even Miniconda can end up taking up several GB of space though, depending on how many environments you create. Of course, everything has to be the same architecture, but it seems you're willing to manage that.

Comment: @darthbith, yes I could do that, or specify the regular installation folder, or possibly using symlinks. The question is (maybe not explicitly enough): Can I expect that to work? Is there something in the environment structure or contents that is machine-specific and would break if transferred somewhere else?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. The only file that I can think of that conda puts outside the installation prefix is the user config file in `~/.condarc`, and there *may* be files in `~/.conda`. You'll just have to try it :-)